# superagent-bluebird-promise cannot GET

Tags: promise, bluebird, superagent

I'm using superagent-bluebird-promise, and the following gives me a 404 error, "cannot GET /v1/result". Have confirmed it works when I call it via Postman. What am I doing wrong?

```
it('should return a result', function(done){
    stub.login(userId);
    request.get('http://localhost:8080/v1/result/')
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        expect(res.body).to.have.lengthOf(1);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        expect(error).to.not.exist;
    })
    .finally(function(){
        stub.logout();
        done();
    });         
});
```

Comment: Is `login` asynchronous? Do you get the page if you're logged out?

Comment: If I comment out stub.login(), I get the same results. (Live, if I don't log in I get a 401 instead of a 404).

Answer (score 1):

superagent-bluebird-promise is based on supertest

Assuming that stub.login sets some cookie, then you would require them in the next request.

For that you need an agent. (app may be optional)

var agent = request.agent(app)
agent.request(...)

Perform the login on the agent, then do the request on it too.